# Can I write an array to a Panda DataFrame row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have **a table** like this

```
id q         
1  hello?     
2  helloWorld 
3  hi
```

I want to create **another column with name 'k'** like this,

```
id q              k
1  hello?        [h,e,l,o]
2  helloWorld    [h,e,l,o,w,r,d]
3  hi            [h, i]
```

The **type of k row is nparray**,
is this **possible** with Pandas?

Comment: if you already have the rows of k stored somehow, like in a variable kData, then you'd just do existing_dataframe['k'] = kData. However, it's unclear what you have in memory and what you want to do. Are you generating the rows of k from the existing dataframe?

Comment: I have a `kValue = [h, e, l, o]` , I want to insert something like `existing_dataframe['k'][0] = kValue`

Comment: Then your kValues should be included in the body of your question.

Comment: I think I was able to do this somehow, thanks for the answers, though it is helpful for me

Comment: it is just an example, I thought panda rows doesn't accept array values, but apparently it do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try filtering out non-alphabetical characters with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) + [`pd.unqiue`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html#pandas-unique):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'q': ['hello?', 'helloWorld', 'hi']
})

df['k'] = df['q'].replace(r'\W', '', regex=True) \
    .apply(lambda x: pd.unique(list(x.lower())))

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   id           q                      k
0   1      hello?           [h, e, l, o]
1   2  helloWorld  [h, e, l, o, w, r, d]
2   3          hi                 [h, i]
```

---

Or if order doesn't matter `set` is an option:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'q': ['hello?', 'helloWorld', 'hi']
})

df['k'] = df['q'].replace(r'\W', '', regex=True) \
    .apply(lambda x: np.array([*set(x.lower())]))

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   id           q                      k
0   1      hello?           [h, o, l, e]
1   2  helloWorld  [o, e, r, d, h, l, w]
2   3          hi                 [i, h]
```